# Error installing SQL Server - Wait on the database engine recovery handle failed

Tags: sql-server, windows-11

This is the Message:

> The following error has occurred:
>
> Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.

I already try to set the account name to NT/Authority in NetworkService, System, Local Network and the same error

Is in Windows 11 so I already try to set the commmand in CMD as administrator and still not working

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device" /v "ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes" /t   REG_MULTI_SZ /d "* 4095" /f
```

Comment: Did you do as the error tells you and *"Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes."*?

Comment: What version of windows 11 and version of SQL Server

Comment: WINDOWS 11 HOME-21H2 the version of sql i try the 2017 Enterprise and the SQL Express 2019 but none work

Comment: Now it shows this one: The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.

Comment: @itsFerxis Any update on solving this issue?

Comment: Hi @dcruise546 unfortunately I couldn't find a solution to my issue, I tried installations with all kind of versions and type the commands to force the expand the byte size and nothing

Comment: I have added the registry key in Windows 11 as mentioned above, I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but when running the Reg CMD statement it worked as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).